# How to use same validation method for two action methods

Tags: java, validation, struts2, struts2-interceptors

I have an action Method and validation method for this method in Struts2. I want to use this validation method for another action method. I have no Idea how to do it. Please help. The scenario is described below:

```
public class ApplicantRegistrationDetails extends ActionSupport {
    
     public String personOfCollectiveTrademark() {
      // some code..
         
     }

     public String insertAndValidateIECcode(){
        // I have to use same validation method
        // for this method as above.

     }

     //validation
     public void validatePersonOfCollectiveTrademark() {
       // validations for first method
     }

}
```

Comment: I have several other validation methods for other action methods so I can not use overridden @validate{} method.

Comment: Move code from `validatePersonOfCollectiveTrademark` to some method, create `validateInsertAndValidateIECcode` method call new method from both of them.

Comment: @AleksandrM Actually I want the same validation method to be called for both of two action methods by validation Interceptor.

Comment: I understand that, but you cannot do it easily. The point is to avoid code duplication, and for this read my first comment.

Comment: okey. I am gonna do that but can you upvote the question so that other people get attention over it.!

Comment: The validation interceptor works in a very specific way: you can have a `validate()` method, you can have `validateXxx()` methods, you can have annotations, and you can have XML. Those are your options without non-trivial work on the existing, or a new, validation interceptor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it easily by using prefix based method validation.

```
 /**
  * Validates insertAndValidateIECcode()
  */
 public void  validateInsertAndValidateIECcode(){
    // The implementation uses same validation method
    // for personOfCollectiveTrademark().
    validatePersonOfCollectiveTrademark();
 }
```